# Mono on embedded ARM experience?

Tags: mono, embedded, arm

I'm evaluating components for a new embedded platform. CPU is an ARM9 and OS is Linux. Because the platform will be in use at least for 10 years I think the language should be chosen carefully as well. I'm already running Mono on possible target platform. Beside that I'm to dumb to compile Mono with my Compiler (according to Google more or less everyone else has the same problems), it's already running. I've written some benchmarks for our specific needs and I was quite impressed that Mono was never more than twice as slow compared to plain C. Memory usage is OK, and when I remove all unneeded files the footprint is acceptable. I just like to know if anyone else uses Mono on an embedded platform? Did you have any problems? Things which everyone should consider?

Comment: do you managed to build a minimal mono small-footprint build by cross compiling for arm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the iPhone and Android are ARM, Mono is very well supported on ARM.  And because Novell sells supported versions of Mono targeting those platforms, it is likely to stay well supported for quite some time.

One thing to note is the Mono runtime is licensed under the LGPL, so you need to ensure your usage complies with the license, or you will need to purchase a commercial license for Mono.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (Although I am not sure myself, whether it is good sign, when the only feedback is from the inventors themselves. Regardless if it is true).